# Sharepoint Lists

Tags: list

I would like to know if I can use an existing list as a template but to exclude some columns before creating the list template. Or alternatively exporting to excel but keeping the options of drop down lists etc. as when I export to excel it loses the choice fields and makes it a text field and I have to redo all the choices.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you export the list as a template, this will produces a .stp file.

This file is actually a simple cab file you can extract, tweak, and rebuild.

Depending on the complexity of the tweak, you can either :

1. export the list as a stp file, then tweak it, then rebuild the stp
2. export the list, reimport in a temp list, tweak the temp list, then reexport the temporary list
3. Move to Visual and a custom list definition

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Export the list as an .STP file
2. Import the list back into SharePoint into a new location.
3. Delete the columns you don't want.

Additionally, you may rename the .STP file to a .CAB file, extract Manifest.xml from the .CAB file, modify Manifest.xml.  If you use NotePad++ and the XML tools to do this, it's actually not that hard, you just have to collapse all the elements and open the ones you want and then you may delete them.